# Why does my reverse SSH tunnel get closed after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, isp

I'm curious as to why my reverse SSH tunnel closes after a certain amount of time has passed while being inactive. Is this related to the specific ISP? I'm trying to reverse tunnel into a virtual linux box. I can connect remotely after killing the PID and then restarting autossh. This only works for about 10 minutes though.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the following are set in your `sshd_config` file on the machine you are tunnelling to:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 9999
```

These settings will make sure your connection is kept alive even when inactive.

Comment: This is just **wrong**. `ClientAliveCountMax` specifies *the number of keepalive messages which are ok to go AWOL before the connection is dropped*. This is the opposite of what you want. Just leave this option away. [See here for more info.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475075/serveraliveinterval-and-serveralivecountmax).

Answer (score 0):

Normally I don't answer a question with just a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqedV1EdO8Q).  This episode of Hak5 explains reverse tunnels and addresses specifically why a reverse tunnel gets shut off, and what to do about it.

Comment: I will be watching this tonight. Thank you very much.

Comment: that links now gets you a 404 error.

Comment: The link has been updated to the same youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

A short timeout usually is related to some kind of time out set in a firewall or NAT device.  The simple solution is just to pass the ssh option to set the `ServerAliveInterval`.  Which just sends a periodic packet to keep the connection alive.

```
Host remote.example.org
    ServerAliveInterval 60  # 60 seconds sounds good?
    Hostname 192.168.1.1
```

Then just connect with `ssh remote.example.org`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did this along with 'ServerAliveCountMax #' where # is the amount of attempts to perform 'ServerAliveInterval' at which ever predetermined interval (in the example above, 60 seconds).